# How do I pass a specific string to my partial depending on the value of another variable also being passed to it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, partials

I have the following partial (`_card_brand.html.erb`), which looks like this:

```
<div class="payment-card">
    <i class="fa fa-cc-<%= brand.downcase %> payment-icon-big text-success"></i>
</div>
```

That renders HTML that looks like this:

```
<div class="payment-card">
    <i class="fa fa-cc-visa payment-icon-big text-success"></i>
</div>
```

The above is rendered with this:

```
<%= render partial: "subscriptions/card_brand", locals: { brand: current_user.card_brand } %>
```

What I want to do is change the class `text-success`, to be either: `text-warning, text-primary, text-danger, etc.` depending on if the card has `brand: visa, amex, mastercard, discovery, etc.`

So:

> - Visa = Success
> - AMEX = Warning
> - Mastercard = Primary
> - Discovery = Danger

Any other cards would be other classes.

How do I elegantly represent that in my view that renders the partial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create a helper and use it so that it will be easy to add new classes as well.

**application_helper.rb**

```
CARD_CLASS = {
  'visa' => 'success',
  'amex' => 'warning',
  'mastercard' => 'primary',
  'discovery' => 'danger'
}

def payment_class(type)
  CARD_CLASS[type.downcase]
end
```

**_card_brand.html.erb**

```
<div class="payment-card">
    <i class="fa fa-cc-<%= brand.downcase %> payment-icon-big text-text-<%= payment_class(brand.downcase) %>"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: I assume you meant for the `text-<%= payment_class(brand.downcase) %>`.